# Show injectivity of the composition of two injective functions

Tags: functions

How would one prove that the composition of two injective functions, $g$ and $f$, is also injective? Is there a way I can demonstrate this using logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So say $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z.$ Say we have $x_1,x_2\in X$ with $(g\circ f)(x_1)=(g\circ f)(x_2).$ Then $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2)),$ and by injectivity of $g$ also $f(x_1)=f(x_2).$ Injectivity of $f$ implies now $x_1=x_2,$ and thus $g\circ f$ is injective.

Comment: Brilliant, that clears it up. Seems so simple now I can see the solution haha

Answer (score 1):

For all $x$ and $y$ defined

$f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right) \Rightarrow x=y$

$g\left(x\right)=g\left(y\right) \Rightarrow x=y$

Hence suppose
$$
f\circ g\left(x\right)=f\circ g\left(y\right) \text{ which means }f\left( g\left(x\right)\right)=f\left( g\left(y\right)\right)
$$
By $f$ injectivity
$$
g\left(x\right)=g\left(y\right) \left(\Rightarrow x=y\right)$$
Hence $f \circ g$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be two injective functions. So, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$ and $g(y_1)=g(y_2)\implies y_1=y_2$.
$$
g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)\implies g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))\\\implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)\text{ since $g$ is injective}\\\implies x_1=x_2\text{ since f is injective}
$$

Thus, $g\circ f(x_1)=g\circ f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$, hence $g\circ f$ is injective. For $g\circ f$ to be injective $f$ must be injective and $g$ may or may not be injective.
$$
f\circ g(y_1)=f\circ g(y_2)\implies f(g(y_1))=f(g(y_2))\\\implies g(y_1)=g(y_2)\text{ since $f$ is injective}\\\implies y_1=y_2\text{ since g is injective}
$$
$f\circ g(y_1)=f\circ g(y_2)\implies y_1=y_2$, hence $f\circ g$ is injective. For $f\circ g$ to be injective $g$ must be injective and $f$ may or may not be injective.